# How to set up title of Scene component in react-native-router-flux

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I have normal Scene component of react-native-router-flux. I want to set up title of Scene. How can I set up title's properties.

For example I want backgroundColor of title :"red",
alignItems:"center" like this.

```
return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="login"
          component={LoginForm}
          title="Login"
        />
      </Scene>
    </Router>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the prop `titleStyle` like this way:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    navigationBarTitleStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
    }
});

return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="login"
          component={LoginForm}
          title="Login"
          titleStyle={styles.navigationBarTitleStyle}
        />
      </Scene>
    </Router>
)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this worked for you please, check this answer as "The correct Answer".